# LogBack vulnerability

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

I want to ask you about the new version 1.2.9 of Logback that have been released concerning [LOGBACK-1591](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1591)

Logback are saying that  the vulnerability mentioned in CVE-2021-42550 requires write access to logback's configuration file as a prerequisite

And i'm using logback < 1.2.9 on my spring boot project, but i don't have a logback.xml, i'm just using some logging properties on the application.properties

Could you telle me please if i'm concerned about this vulnerability or not ?

Thnak you in advance.

Comment: I assume, this question is better fit for logback forums ?

Comment: Did you research on the sister-site [security.se]? There are [some answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257943/am-i-protected-from-log4j-vulnerability-if-i-run-java-8u121-or-newer/257964#257964) already.

Comment: if you are using application.properties and it is not writeable, you are good to go. Why not just upgrade?

Comment: I don't know where i can find a logback forums,

Comment: If you are not using a custom logback config XML and only rely on [Spring-Boot's default logback configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348674/understanding-spring-boot-2s-default-logback-configuration), there would be nothing to have write-access to.

Comment: Yes, i'm not using a custom logback config, like i said, i'm using some properties on application.properties like the level of logs, the file path ... this is why i'm confused about this write access think